# How to minimize all windows/applications to the dock?

Tags: macos, keyboard

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as mentioned in multiple docs only appears to minimize the current (focused) window.

I am looking for the "Show Desktop" equivalent.  If it matters I'm using 10.6.4.

Comment: The question asks how to minimize all windows TO THE DOCK, not hide them or show the desktop. Somehow, mac people are happy to "hide" a window rather than minimizing to the dock, but I prefer the latter. No one has attempted to answer the question, I'm disappointed to say. I guess it's because it can't be done. Too bad.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> actually minimizes all windows of a current application, not just the current focused window (unless of course, the application you have running only has one non-minimized window.)

The easiest way to hide all active applications is to select the Finder/Desktop, and then "Hide Others." The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

You can also simply hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> and click on the Desktop, or Finder on the Dock, or of course, simply use Expose and hit <kbd>F11</kbd> (Or whatever you've rebound Hide-all to.)

Comment: Didn't realize the differentiation between focused/other windows of an app before.
 
Option-Command-H works as planned.  If you have a app focused it will leave that one alone also.

Comment: Yup, hence my suggestion to select the Finder first if you want to show desktop. It's actually "Hide Others", not "Hide All", so that makes sense.

Comment: Careful for apps that override the default keystrokes with their own. Photoshop is particularly annoying in this regard.

Comment: Love the [command] + [option] + [click on desktop] tip - that's really useful!

Comment: I always switched to finder and then used Hide Others, never knew you could click the icon on the dock to do it though!  Very handy tip thanks

Comment: hiding != minimizing!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I just use Hot Corners to do it.

System Preferences >> Desktop & Screen Saver >> Hot Corners >> Select "Desktop" from one of the dropdowns. I use the bottom left, since that's where I was used to the Desktop button in XP lol.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to do it with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

This works for me on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work if you have Firefox running.