# Truly Minimize All Windows

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to minimize all windows/applications to the dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156/how-to-minimize-all-windows-applications-to-the-dock)

I am aware of the F11 shortcut, but that doesn't really minimize all windows - it moves them to different corners and then when I open something up they ALL come back. The closest thing I have to making this work is by pressing F11, then Command + Option + Desktop click.

Are there any easier ways?

Comment: Is the goal for the windows to be truly minimized (i.e. there are thumbnail icons in the Dock ready to be clicked to reappear), or for them to semi-permanantly go away (like with F11 but where they don't come flying back when you open something)?

Comment: Either/or, really. I'm not THAT picky. ;)

Comment: tell application "System Events"
 set theButtons to {}
 
 repeat with theApplication in application processes
  repeat with theWindow in windows of theApplication
   repeat with theButton in buttons of theWindow
    if ((description of theButton) is "minimize button") then
     set theButtons to theButtons & {theButton}
    end if
   end repeat
  end repeat
 end repeat
 
 repeat with theButton in theButtons
  click theButton
 end repeat
end tell

Answer (score 0):

Try the Finder keyboard shortcut Option-Command-M. Other very handy shortcuts are available on [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) at the Apple Support site. Hope this helps.

Comment: That just seems to minimize my current window.

Comment: ... and all windows associated with that program. For example, having two Google Chrome windows open will minimize both of them, but not Xcode, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Click on desktop area (or just switch Finder) then just hit CMD+ALT+H.

Comment: Is there no easy way to do this without having to do multiple clicks/shortcuts?

Comment: I think you can create an app with Automator (https://skitch.com/fatihturan/f6th7/automator) and run this app with BetterTouchTool or something like this (http://www.boastr.de/) via keyboard binding.